# How to access the camera image using Vuforia for Android

Tags: android, vuforia

How to access the captured camera image using the Vuforia SDK on Android.
All the answers point to Vuforia Unity and the exposed API is very different from Android's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to achieve even in the native API. It is explained in several of the Vuforia forum posts. Here is the formal article one: [How To Access the Camera Image using the Native APIs](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Access-the-Camera-Image-the-Native-APIs)

Update: Apparently, the link is broken. The answer can also be found here: [Access camera image](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-the-Camera#How-To-Access-the-Camera-Image-in-Native)

Comment: there is an error in the official documentation
line 17 should be:
pixels.get(pixelArray, 0, pixelArray.length);

There is no need to -1

Comment: OK, feel free to tell them... Anyway, if the answer helped you, feel free to accept it...

Comment: Please take into consideration that google results are not the same depending on the connected account. First results for you are not for me.

Comment: I do not know what you are referring to - anyway, I went to Vuforia's website and forum to dig this up for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: The link appears to be broken. Can anyone provide an update?